# Angular 4 and ngx-datatable: 'ngx-datatable' is not a known element

Tags: javascript, angular, datatable, systemjs, ngx-datatable

I try to use `ngx-datatable` in my angular 4 project using system.js to load the module, but it throws errors like this:

> Can't bind to 'rows' since it isn't a known property of ngx-datatable.
>   Can't bind to 'columns' since it isn't a known property of ngx-datatable.
>   ngx-datatable is not a known element:

I guess system.js does not load the module correctly but i can't find a working demo on how to do this. The [documentation](https://swimlane.gitbooks.io/ngx-datatable/introduction/installing.html) is not helpful either.

system.config.js:

```
map: {
     ...
     '@swimlane/ngx-datatable': 'npm:@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/index.js',
     ...
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgxDatatableModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';
...
imports: [
    ...
    NgxDatatableModule,
    ...
],
```

component.html:

```
<ngx-datatable
     [rows]="rows"
     [columns]="columns">
</ngx-datatable>
```

component.ts:

```
rows = [
    { name: 'Austin', gender: 'Male', company: 'Swimlane' },
    { name: 'Dany', gender: 'Male', company: 'KFC' },
    { name: 'Molly', gender: 'Female', company: 'Burger King' },
];
columns = [
    { prop: 'name' },
    { name: 'Gender' },
    { name: 'Company' }
];
```

package.json:

```
...
"@angular/animations": "^4.3.0",
"@angular/common": "^4.3.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.3.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.3.0",
"@angular/core": "^4.3.0",
"@angular/forms": "^4.3.0",
"@angular/http": "^4.3.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "^4.3.0",
"@angular/router": "^4.3.0",
"@angular/upgrade": "4.3.0",
"@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^9.3.1",
...
```

Comment: did you run `npm install`?

Answer (score 8):

I installed it running properly for  me.
Please refer this [link](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-datatable/getting-started)

```
Please import in App.module.ts like below:

    import { NgxDatatableModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NgxDatatableModule]});
```

Please see the App.component.html

```
 <ngx-datatable class="material"
            [rows]="rows"
            [columns]="column">
          </ngx-datatable>
```

Answer (score 5):

In the brackets, try to add `attr` before `rows` or any other attribute.
It should be like this `[attr.rows]="rows"`and `[attr.columns]="columns"` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem that was solved by running

```
ng update
```

I am not sure what was wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working  using this approach

1. add ref to the HTML code

   <ngx-datatable #myTable
   [rows]="rows"
   [columns]="columns">
2. `import { DatatableComponent } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';`
3. `@ViewChild('myTable') myTable!: DatatableComponent;`

Do not forget to `import ViewChild  from '@angular/core';`